# Normalize String Data from Text file

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I Have data in below format in textfile, need data in normalize form one below another ie.

Current data is in below form,

1,354,1116,4296,49888
2,2029
3,7092,12834,26651,52362

Need data in below form :

1,354

1,1116

1,4296

1,49888

2,2029

3,7092

.

.

.

3,52362

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest way:

```
a = '1,354,1116,4296,49888 2,2029 3,7092,12834,26651,52362'

b = ''
for i in a.split():
    for n, j in enumerate(i.split(',')):
        if n:
            print('{},{}'.format(i[0], j)) # or file.write()
```

**Output**:

```
1,354 
1,1116 
1,4296 
1,49888 
2,2029 
3,7092 
3,12834 
3,26651 
3,52362
```

**Updated**:

```
file = open('test.txt', 'w+')
file.write('1,354,1116,4296,49888 2,2029 3,7092,12834,26651,52362\n')

# file.txt:
#
# 1,354,1116,4296,49888 2,2029 3,7092,12834,26651,52362
#

with open('test.txt', 'a+') as file:
    for line in file.read().split():
        for n, j in enumerate(line.split(',')):
            if n:
                file.write('{},{}\n'.format(line[0], j))

# file.txt:
#
# 1,354,1116,4296,49888 2,2029 3,7092,12834,26651,52362
# 1,354
# 1,1116
# 1,4296
# 1,49888
# 2,2029
# 3,7092
# 3,12834
# 3,26651
# 3,52362
#
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, have data in text file and need to append result in text file, could you please help for same